# Joining large number of data frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, out-of-memory

I have an array of data frames which I join using the column "id" to create a larger dataframe

```
val dfArray = Array.fill[DataFrame](n)(spark.emptyDataFrame)
dfArray(0) = df_0
dfArray(1) = df_1
...
dfArray(n) = df_n

val output = dfArray.reduceLeft(_.join(_, Seq("id")))
```

If I try to perform any action (Ex: `output.show`) on `output` it takes a really long time. Sometimes crashes with OOM errors. However, if I write `output` to a file and read it back to a different variable it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is and how to resolve it.

Comment: What type of storage are you using?

Comment: What do you mean? All these operation are performed in memory except when I write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that `show` requires a `collect` that centralizes the required data to the application driver, while writing to the file (even if no code is provided) does not.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was referring to the action `show` performed on two dataframes. If I perform `show` on output, it takes few minutes. However, if I write ouput to a file (ex: `output.wirte.csv(path)`) and load it back to another variable (Ex: `val output2 = spark.read.csv(path)`) and then perform a `show` on `output2` it only takes few seconds. I was expecting both show operations to take similar time intervals given that `output` is cached in memory. But it's not.

Comment: Actually, once you've done `dfArray.reduceLeft(_.join(_, Seq("id")))` nothing has been done yet (spark is lazy). Even if you have added `.cache()`. For the `show` to work, spark has to perform the joins (at least enough of it to be able to print the first lines), this is why it takes time. On the contrary, once the df is written on the disk, showing a sample is effortless.

Comment: Regarding your question about the OOM that only occurs when you do not write the data first, i have an idea but I would need to know more about your backend (where is the cluster and what type of storage you use).

Comment: @Oli currently this is not running on a cluster. I'm running this locally for testing.

Comment: You should provide more details and the entire code you are testing

Comment: @Oli Your comment about spark being lazy makes sense. But I was under the impression that `.cache()` actually performs the tasks so its doesn't have to do it all over again on consecutive calls. So, how do I force spark to do the actual computations and store the answer in memory?

Comment: `.cache()` keeps the result in memory for further use, but only after the first time it needs to be computed. Not before. The only way to make spark compute things is to collect to the driver, or write to the storage system. As long as you just pill up transformations, nothing concrete happens.

Comment: Exactly `cache()` is a transformation, not an action